# A "uniform" probability measure on the set of probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

As a premise, this is a rather informal question. I just would like to know if there is a "natural" candidate for "uniform" probability measure on the set of probability measures, whatever this may mean.

A bit more precisely:

> **Question.** Let $\Delta$ be the set of probability measures $\mu: \mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{R}}\to \mathbf{R}$, where $\mathscr{B}_{\mathbf{R}}$ stands for the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets. Endow $\Delta$ with the topology of weak convergence, so that $(\mu_n)$ is convergent to $\mu$ means that $\lim_n\int f\mathrm{d}\mu_n=\int f\mathrm{d}\mu$ for every bounded countinuous function $f:\mathbf{R}\to \mathbf{R}$; and denote by $\mathscr{B}_{\Delta}$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Is there a "natural uniform" probability measure
> $$
> P: \mathscr{B}_{\Delta} \to \mathbf{R}?
> $$

Comment: One could imagine a definition of “uniform” distribution as one which maximizes some “entropy”. See [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.11184). As a start, it may make more sense if $\Delta$ were the set of probability measures on a *compact* (metric) space, in which case $\Delta$ itself is compact (for the topology of weak convergence).

Comment: @nejimban This is an interesting suggestion, thank you. If I understood correctly, Definition 9.2 provides the notion of "uniform measure" on a compact metric space (in our case, we could take e.g. any metrizable compactification of $\mathbf{R}$). In following results, the authors show that such uniform measure exists and coincides with the natural candidates (in cases e.g. of homogeneous spaces and compact subsets of $\mathbf{R}^n$ with nonempty interior). However, it is unclear whether a "uniform measure" exists even in the case of $X=\{\text{probability measures on }[0,1]\}$, is it correct?

Comment: According to Definition 9.2., yes, it is not clear whether such a uniform measure exists in the case you are mentioning. However, (I haven't checked all details) it seems Theorem 7.1 may apply, so there exists a measure maximizing entropy.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a uniform measure? what properties would you like it to have? If you want it to satisfy some kind of translation invariance then in general the answer is no.

For something which makes sense see this paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-37/issue-3/Entropic-measure-and-Wasserstein-diffusion/10.1214/08-AOP430.fullr by Sturm and von-Renesse where they construct a type of entropic measure, i.e. essentially they weight measures by their entropy and manage to construct a sensible object.

This is a bit of a simplification: what they really do is construct a measure whose "Cameron-Martin space" is the set of measures with finite entropy (the quotes are present due to the fact that the final measure is not Gaussian and so the Cameron-Martin space does not really make sense.) They also derive a change of variables theorem for the measure. This should really be a comment but it was a bit too long.